# Reset nonce to 0

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, nonce

Using hardhat and ethers.js, how do I reset the nonce queue to 0? Not submitting a new tx with the nonce of the one that's stuck.

For example, the latest nonce I have is 432 and I want to reset it to 0.

Comment: If you were to switch to Foundry, this would be trivially to do with the [`setNonce`](https://book.getfoundry.sh/cheatcodes/set-nonce?highlight=nonce#signature) cheatcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the setNonce(address, nonce) method in hardhat.

See: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/reference